# How to convert "k%C3%B6nnen" to können"

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Code below works fine (puts význam above deklination table on cs.wiktionary.org)  when I run it on https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/gehen but doesn't work on https://cs.wiktionary.org/wiki/k%C3%B6nnen The problem as I see it is that `word` inserts as k%C3%B6nnen instead of können. And thus the css path is invalid. Please help me (I'm a very much beginner in JS).

```
  var word = window.location.href.split("/").pop();
  console.log(word);
  var h = document.getElementsByClassName("konjugace verbum")[0];
  var nadpis = document.querySelector("html.client-js.ve-not-available body.mediawiki.ltr.sitedir-ltr.mw-hide-empty-elt.ns-0.ns-subject.mw-editable.page-"+word+".rootpage-"+word+".skin-vector.action-view.skin-vector-legacy.minerva--history-page-action-enabled div#content.mw-body div#bodyContent.mw-body-content div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr div.mw-parser-output h4 span#význam.mw-headline"); 
  var vyznam = document.querySelector("html.client-js.ve-not-available body.mediawiki.ltr.sitedir-ltr.mw-hide-empty-elt.ns-0.ns-subject.mw-editable.page-"+word+".rootpage-"+word+".skin-vector.action-view.skin-vector-legacy.minerva--history-page-action-enabled div#content.mw-body div#bodyContent.mw-body-content div#mw-content-text.mw-content-ltr div.mw-parser-output ol");
  nadpis.innerHTML = nadpis.innerHTML.bold();
  h.insertAdjacentElement("beforebegin", nadpis);
  nadpis.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", vyznam);
```

Comment: `decodeURIComponent('k%C3%B6nnen'); // "können"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the decodeURIComponent(uri) function.
`decodeURIComponent('K%C3%B6nnen');`
gives `"Können"`
And
`encodeURIComponent('Können');` gives
`"K%C3%B6nnen"`